# npm install throwing UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY error when package.json has the correct version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Trying to install recharts, react-interactjs etc. and getting the following error...

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.4.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@15.4.1
`-- recharts@0.20.0
```

package.json Deps and Dev Deps

```
"dependencies": {
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.63.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-jest": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-plugin-recharts": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "jest": "^18.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.1",
    "recharts": "^0.20.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "worker-loader": "^0.7.1"
  }
```

Tried npm cache clean, deleting node_modules and running npm install. Updating npm, re-installing react and react-dom, and finally also Node. But the error doesn't go away. Also tried dropping caret and installing 15.4.1 for react and react-dom

Node 6.9.2 and npm 4.0.5

Anyone experienced this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Probably the library expects 15.4.1 version and you have a version greater that 15.4.1 as you have written '^15.4.1'.

Comment: Thats what I meant when I said I tried dropping the caret and it still didn't help. I tried 15.4.1 and clean npm install but got the same errror.

Comment: Try removing `"recharts": "^0.20.0"` and/or `"react": "^15.4.1"` from your dependencies, if `react-dom@15.4.1` has a peer dependency with `react@15.4.1`, `react@15.4.1` package will come along with it and so on.

Comment: Tried react-dom@15.4.1 and works ok until I try installing react-interactjs when I get the error message. After that any npm install results in the error. Pretty strange.BTW the dependencies have to still be installed as the new version of npm does not auto install deps.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
npm install react@15.4.1 react-dom@15.4.1
```

before running:

```
npm install
```

If it works then you may want to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`.

Comment: Tried that too but without success. I get the same error.